# How to get back my data from a button to an other php page

Tags: php

I have a button on a php page with some data on this same page. My button redirect to an other php page and I want to get back this data.

I tried to do

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    echo($data);
}
```

The isset is true (I do a test with a string) but I can't get back my datas from this other php page.

My form code of my button :

```
   <form action = "/lienPaybox.php" method = "post">
      <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = 'Submit'> 
   </form>
```

Comment: is it a form on first page?

Comment: The form of the button directed to the new php page where I want to get back these datas.

Comment: You could either store the data in $_SESSION on the second page after doing what you need and then call the $_SESSION values on the first page, or then perhaps use AJAX - Or a third option would be to submit the data from the second page via a form once more and then use jQuery / JS to autosubmit the second form.

Comment: means your button work like a link?

Comment: We can say that @anantkumarsingh

Comment: I can use only PHP mySQL so I will try to do that with $_SESSION, it's complicated ?

Comment: Please show your form code along with button code.thanks

Comment: I'd say no, it's not overly complicated, although as always it depends on your skill level.

Comment: I am in IT classe for one year. We do mainly Java and PHP - MySQL @Epodax

Comment: there is nothing in $_POST. because you don't even have any element in your form code. so how you will get values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to pass datas from one page to another, `Session` is your best bet

All you have to do is initiate session.

`page1.php` --> This page contains your datas. Below code in your page1.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] ='Mr.x';
$_SESSION['usertype'] = 'level1';

?>
```

`page2.php` --> Page from where you want to retrieve datas of page1.php.Here is the code,

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); //You will notice the datas from previous page is being displayed here

?>
```

Ofcourse there are best practices which needs to be followed while handling `Sessions`. Once you get a hang of `sessions`, you can go over this link [Securing Sessions in PHP](http://eddmann.com/posts/securing-sessions-in-php/)

Comment: Thanks you I successed this with $_SESSION. I do that and it works.

Comment: This is strange xD. Then @Epodax said me to do that, I tried then I successed I came back here and I saw your answer. Thanks you even though :)